# Access class generic type parameter on static class property - TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've a BaseEntity class in TypeScript which looks like this:

```
export class BaseEntity<TEntity extends BaseEntity<TEntity, TEntityType>, TEntityType extends typeof BaseEntity> {
    public static primaryKeyName: string;

    // Rest of the class
}
```

Now, in this class, I want the type of `public static primaryKeyName` to be `keyof TEntity` instead of `string`, but when I do that, the compiler gives the error

```
TS2302: Static members cannot reference class type parameters.
```

So, is there a way to reference generic type on static properties?

Comment: *"So, is there a way to reference generic type on static properties?"* The error message is the answer to this question. It does not make logical sense for a static property to have a type depending on the class's type parameter, so whatever the reason is that you think you need to do this (which you didn't say in your question), you need to do something else instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A [mre] with some indication of the use case would be helpful here, otherwise you're just going to get "no" as an answer.